# Need a code-generation tool for entities' DAO's

Tags: java, jpa, maven-2, code-generation

I have lots of entities in a project and I need to make a data-access-object for every one of them. I think those DAO's will be stateless session beans, each having an entity manager injected into it (I'm not sure on this one, but since I'll be using them in the context of JBoss AS, it looks reasonable. Any advice?).
Is there any tool (ideally, a maven plugin) that can scan my entity classes, process their annotations and generate those beans for me? Each bean should expose methods to create or delete entities, as well as each of the named queries of its respective entity class as a separate method.
To be more precise, I want something like in this article:
 http://community.jboss.org/people/ilya40umov/blog/2011/01/06/genericejb-based-jpa-entitymanager-extension 
but with different methods for each named query.
I'll be using JPA 2.0, with Hibernate 4.0. Thanks in advance!
Edit: Stupid me, I forgot to mention that I'm not using spring, and the term DAO is just used to illustrate what I want...

Answer (score 4):

Telosys Tools is designed for this kind of task
It generates code from the database model

See https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/

You can use a part of this tutorial https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/springmvc-jpa-springdatajpa to generate only the JPA part

You can also create your own templates in order to match you own needs (or adapt existing templates)

Answer (score 1):

you could use  generics and reflection to make something like that

```
public interface IDao<T> {


public <A extends Serializable> T getElementByID(A x);

public Long getRowsCount();

public List<T> getAll();

public List<T> getAll(String order);

public void saveOrUpdateElement(T x);

public void updateElement(T x);

public void saveElement(T x);

public void deleteElement(T x);

public void setClase(Class<T> clase);

public Class<T> getClase();

public void mergeElement(T x);

public T getFirst();
```

}

the method public void setClase(Class clase); make all de magic so if you need to query to x then you set the class and the implementaton for example of getAll() will be

```
public List<T> getAll(){
     return session.createQuery("from "+getClase().getSimpleName()).list();
```

}

Comment: I would also opt for generic DAO interface and specific entity-type implementations if it comes to the basic CRUD operations. 

However, this does not solve the problem of automatic namedQuery discovery and methods generation the OP mentioned about. You could of course have a generic method in your CRUD interface which takes the namedQuery name and some type of parameters map, but I doubt it's what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring-Data-JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) or [Spring ROO](http://www.springsource.org/roo)